# Какая альтернатива FPU на x86-64?

Tags: ассемблер, x86, x86-64

Код, производящий вычисления над числами с плавающей точкой использует разные расширения на x86 и x86-64 системах. На x86 это FPU, а на x86-64?

Comment: Тест, что ли, заполняете?

Comment: В чем проблема использовать FPU на x86-64? Нет никакой жесткой привязки FPU только к x86.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Они одинаковые.
В обоих режимах можно использовать два набора инструкций: [`x87`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87) (то что в вопросе, видимо, названо FPU) и [`SSE`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE)(в том числе последующие расширения: `SSE2`/`3`/`4` и т.д.). Конечно, при условии, что конкретный процессор процессор поддерживает данные расширения: `x87` встроен во всё начиная, с i486, а `SSE[2]` во всех ЦП общего назначения со времён Pentium 4.

Для `x86_64` есть мелкие отличия, но сути они не меняют. Например, для `SSE` в длинном режиме доступны *16* регистров (`%xmm0`-`%xmm15`), а не *8*.

Также некоторые компиляторы (`gcc` в частности) для сборки под `x86`-цель обычно по умолчанию используют арифметику основанную на `x87`, а при сборке под `x86_64` — `SSE`.<sup>*</sup> Подробности см. в документации `gcc` к опциям [`-mfpmath`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-mfpmath-1) и [`-ffast-math`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-ffast-math). Большинство других современных компиляторов по умолчанию обычно используют `SSE`-арифметику и для `x86`-целей.

---

<sub>* Cпасибо *@Eugene Ryabtsev* за уточнение</sub>

Comment: Тут надо добавить, что по умолчанию под x86 компилится x87 (для большей совместимости), а под x86-64 идёт SSE2, потому что x86-64 без SSE2 нет, а SSE2 лучше, чем x87. Поменять этот выбор возможно.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev, добавил, но AFAIK это относится только к `gcc`...

Comment: расширенный FPU точней SIMD

Comment: @ИльяК, что?...

Comment: @Fat-Zer числа в FPU можно расширить до 10 байт добавив к мантиссе еще 2 байта и добиться более высокой точности вычисления.

Comment: @ИльяК, нуда, но к вопросу это ИМХО отношения не имеет... ну и кроме того это скорее проблема т.к. вычисления из-за этого не соответствуют ieee754...